# Trying to verify password in the form of PasswordHash and passwordSalt

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core

I have a simple program where a user can register and login running on .net Core 2.2 and Angular 8.
The passwords are stored in a database with a PasswordHash and passwordSalt.
Suddenly the VerifyPassword method stopped working.

While debugging i can see that the ComputedHash array and PasswordHash array are not equal, but the program does not run through the iteration even though the ComputeHash.Length is 64.

So long story short, a user can login with any password it wants.
Any ideas?

[Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fQ1m.png)

Comment: Don't include pictures of code, but the code itself.

Comment: The loop condition is inverted. Should be `i < ComputeHash.Length`

Comment: Yes, i just saw it. Thanks anyway 
And I am going to post the code as text next time